# Start/stop particular EC2 instance from other EC2 instance in same AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway, aws-sdk-nodejs

What is a simple way to start/stop a particular (e.g. with hardcoded identifier) EC2 instance from another EC2 instance (running Node) in the same AWS account?

I am familiar with Node but not with AWS SDK, which I suppose I have to learn. At the same time I wonder whether there may be another AWS service in which I can more easily associate an HTTP resource (e.g. modifiable by credentialed PUT/DELETE) with the state (running/stopped) of particular EC2 instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with either the aws cli or the SDK.

### AWS CLI

A very simple way is just to install the aws cli on the second instance and run

```
aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids i-1234567890abcdef0
```

or

```
aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids i-1234567890abcdef0
```

---

### SDK

If you want to stick with node, then you can start/stop an instance this way using the SDK:

```
 var params = {
  InstanceIds: [
     "i-1234567890abcdef0"
  ]
 };

 /* Start */
 ec2.startInstances(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);           // successful response
 });

 /* Stop */
 ec2.stopInstances(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);           // successful response
 });
```

---

### Important note

Note that the instance's IAM role needs to include the following policy (or equivalent)

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:StartInstances",
        "ec2:StopInstances"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. I'm just reading up about IAM roles to try make more sense of it.

Answer (score 0):

`aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids i-1234567890abcdef0 --region us-east-2`
The instance ids is a space separated list 
If your instances are in autoscaling group then you can also use filters with tags so that you dont have to worry about instance ids